# Leaderboard ranking via elasticsearch (with tire)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I have a mapping that boils down to the following (unrelated fields removed):

```
mapping 
  indexes :id, type: 'integer', index: :not_analyze        
  indexes :first_name, boost: 5, type: 'string', analyzer: 'snowball'
  indexes :votes, type: 'integer', index: :not_analyzed
end
```

At the moment I'm calculating ranking via postgres, so that given the following entries:

```
| first_name | votes |
----------------------
| Andy       |     5 |
| Barry      |     8 |
| Carl       |     5 |
| Derek      |     1 |
```

Using postgres, I can get the following:

```
| first_name | votes | rank |
-----------------------------
| Barry      |     8 |    1 |
| Andy       |     5 |    2 |
| Carl       |     5 |    2 |
| Derek      |     1 |    4 |
```

Is it possible somehow calculate this ranking via elasticsearch?

Comment: Have you thought about using redis? It is perfect for something like this. For elasticsearch, I'd give their `sort` documentation a read over: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort/

Comment: Is the rank calculated relative to the current results, or a total for the entire data set? For example, in your data set is there also 'Sarah' with 10 votes, who would therefore rank 1 with a different query / filter?

Comment: As @DamienRoche said, Redis is the perfect tool for this kind of stuff (assuming that the number of votes and thus the rank change frequently). I wouldn't have thought of ElasticSearch for that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe ElasticSearch is the place to do it, since updating a single document would require recalculation of all ranking values. Not possible, as far as I can tell.

Instead, once you get the results you can use Ruby to calculate the ranking with something like this:

```
scores = {:a=>5, :b=>8, :c=>5, :d=>1}
scores.values.sort{|a,b| a <=> b}.tap do |sorted_scores|
  sorted_scores.each{|vote| puts sorted_scores.index(vote)+1 }
end
```

Comment: Sorting in ruby might not be an option if OP is also looking for pagination along with ranking.

Answer (score 3):

Redis is indeed an ideal solution for leaderboards.  While it is introducing another technology, if you're using AWS, note that ElastiCache managed Redis was [just launched this week](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/amazon-elasticache-now-with-a-dash-of-redis.html).

Generic Redis commands would be:

```
zadd votes 5 "Andy"
zadd votes 8 "Barry"
zadd votes 5 "Carl"
zadd votes 1 "Derek"
```

Then to get the leaderboard with most votes as highest ranked:

```
zrevrange votes 0 -1
```

Refer to the [Redis docs for ZREVRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrange) for more details.

For Ruby on Rails, I'd encourage you to look at my [redis-objects](http://github.com/nateware/redis-objects) gem which is popular since it easily integrates with ActiveRecord.  Assuming you have a table with a `votes` column as shown, you could update the ranking on save:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redis::Objects
  sorted_set :rank, global: true

  after_save :update_rank
  def update_rank
    self.class.rank[id] = votes
  end
end
```

Then retrieve the leaderboard:

```
User.rank.revrange(0, -1)
```

In this example, this will return `id` values which you could then use to retrieve records as follows. (You could also store `first_name` or some other unique value.)

```
ids = User.rank.revrange(0, -1)
users = User.where(id: ids).all
```

You can paginate through results with `revrange` by passing different start/end values:

```
User.rank.revrange(0, 9)
User.rank.revrange(10, 19)
```

You could easily wrap this in a `self.` method in User that retrieved a page of rankings from Redis and returned the DB records accordingly.